# tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask directory structure

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

What would be the directory structure required to successfully run a flask app inside a container using the base image  tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask.

The website mention only the location of the file main.py.

[image]

For more advance project

[image]

**Where are we suppose to locate the folders 'Templates' and "Static' ?**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── app
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── script.js
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   └── templates
    │       └── index.html
    └── uwsgi.ini

4 directories, 7 files
```

You can locate `templates` & `static` wherever you like, however Flask will automatically know how to locate them if they are placed at the same path level as your `app` object creation script. If you decide to place them somewhere else, you may pass in `static_folder` and `template_folder` as keyword arguments with the absolute paths to these folders. If you want to see more details about the way in which Flask loads these files, you can set the `EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING` config value to `True` (it defaults to `False`)

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING=True)
```

This will log the output from the Jinja2 template loading engine, which is what Flask is using behind the scenes to locate its static files.

You find more details about advanced Flask patterns [from the official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. I see you are embedding the app folder in another app folder as shown for advanced project. Can I use only one app folder if I don't have any __init__. py?

Comment: I tried both, the simplest one with only one app folder gave me '502 bad gateway nginx', The second directory structure with the two app folder gave me a 'hello word' that I don't recognize. I am unable to get my index.html page with both directory structure.

Comment: @FritzFABO if you're having trouble with the files themselves you'll have to update the post with their contents.